# Augmented binomial test where p is different for each trial

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, binomial-distribution

A have a model process whereby for each item, $i$, of $N$ total items I estimate a trial success probability $p_i$.

I then have results for each individual process which has resulted in failure (0) or success (1), $r_i$.

If $p_i = p$ for each item, then the test I can perform is a standard binomial test to reject or accept the null hypothesis that $p$ is accurate. But when each item probability differs this seems to be inappropriate, for example, I instinctively think that taking mean values over $N$, and using $\bar{p_i} \sim p$ as the test hypothesis will break the test considering the space of values that each $p_i$ could take.

And if chosen to group the $N$ items into say $K << N$ groups by ordering $p_i$, this limits the dispersion of the $p_i$ values within the group but still feels instinctively incorrect.

Can anyone comment or share a paper?

Comment: I think you could be much clearer if you included actual data with some context. But the good old chi square test comes to mind.

Comment: @BigBendRegion An example is a credit model where each customer loan is assigned an individual probability of default, and in the next year the data about whether that loan defaulted or not becomes known. Then we backtest whether that model was valid for the outcomes given a confidence interval

Comment: I believe your problem might be related to [Poisson Binomial Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_binomial_distribution), but any statistical tests related to this may be complicated due to the number of parameters involved.